# Error while running sonar-ant-task-1.4 with sonar-5.3

Tags: ant, sonarqube

I downloaded zip file for sonarqube-5.3.
http://localhost:9000 works.
I am trying to run 'ant -f antbuild.xml sonar' command.
The ant version is 1.9.2 and sonar-ant task jar has version 1.4.

### I am getting following exception:

```
sonar:
[sonar:sonar] Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
[sonar:sonar] Sonar Ant Task version: 1.4
[sonar:sonar] Loaded from: file:/C:/FI1/runner/sonar-ant-task-1.4.jar
[sonar:sonar] Sonar work directory: C:\FI1\runner\.sonar
[sonar:sonar] Sonar server: http://localhost:9000
[sonar:sonar] Sonar version: 5.3

BUILD FAILED
C:\FI1\runner\antbuild.xml:39: org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapException:
org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapException: Fail to download the file: 
http://localhost:9000/batch/sonar-batch-shaded-5.3.jar|3659a1916b6b99eb1f6567db76884fcd
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.downloadBatchFiles(Bootstrapper.java:164)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.createClassLoader(Bootstrapper.java:87)
        at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.createClassLoader(SonarTask.java:257)
        at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:193)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapException: Fail to download the file: http://localhost:9000/batch/sonar-batch-shaded-5.3.jar|3659a1916b6b99eb1f6567db76884fcd
```

---

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,
Amey

Comment: Are you able to download http://localhost:9000/batch/sonar-batch-shaded-5.3.jar manually?

Answer (score 1):

You must upgrade your [SonarQube Scanner for Ant](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Ant). Your current Ant Task version (1.4) is not compatible with your SonarQube version (5.3). This [compatibility matrix](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Analyzing+Source+Code#AnalyzingSourceCode-CompatibilityMatrix) shows that v2.2 is a minimum requirement since SonarQube 3.7 (2.4 being the best choice for SonarQube 4.5+).